# Blocking folders inbetween allowed content

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a site with the following structure:

```
http://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

I would like to disallow indexing in `folder1`, and `folder2`.
But I would like the robots to index everything under `folder3`.

Is there a way to do this with the robots.txt?

For what I read I think that everything inside a specified folder is disallowed.

Would the following achieve my goal?

```
user-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 0

Sitemap: <Sitemap url>

Allow: /folder1/folder2/folder3
Disallow: /folder1/folder2/
Disallow: /folder1/
Allow: /
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works... however google has a tool to test your robots.txt file

you only need to go on google webmaster tools (https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/)

and open the section "site configuration -> crawler access"

Answer (score 0):

All you would need is:

```
user-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 0

Sitemap: 

Allow: /folder1/folder2/folder3
Disallow: /folder1/
Allow: /
```

At least googlebot will see the more specific allowing of that one directory and disallow anything from `folder1` and on. This is backed up by this [post](http://groups.google.com/group/Google_Webmaster_Help-Indexing/browse_thread/thread/dfa31079d671315a?pli=1) by a Google employee.

Comment: Yes. Thank you I didn't escape the escape some things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Line breaks in records are not allowed, so your original robots.txt should look like this:

```
user-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 0
Sitemap: <Sitemap url>
Allow: /folder1/folder2/folder3
Disallow: /folder1/folder2/
Disallow: /folder1/
Allow: /
```

Possible improvements:

- Specifying `Allow: /` is superfluous, as it’s the default anyway.
- Specifying `Disallow: /folder1/folder2/` is superfluous, as `Disallow: /folder1/` is sufficient.
- As `Sitemap` is not per record, but for all bots, you could specify it as a separate block.

So your robots.txt could look like this:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 0
Allow: /folder1/folder2/folder3
Disallow: /folder1/

Sitemap: http://example.com/sitemap
```

(Note that the `Allow` field is not part of the original [robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html), so don’t expect all bots to understand it.)