# EHow to Disallow few list of URL crawled by google crawler using robots.txt

Tags: url, robots.txt, googlebot

I have couple of pages and URL which I do not want to be crawled by Google crawler.

I know it can be done via robots.txt. I search Google and found this way we need to arrange the whole things in robots.txt for disallow crawler but I am not sure does it right or not.

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /music?
Disallow: /widgets/radio?

Disallow: /affiliate/
Disallow: /affiliate_redirect.php
Disallow: /affiliate_sendto.php
Disallow: /affiliatelink.php
Disallow: /campaignlink.php
Disallow: /delivery.php

Disallow: /music/+noredirect/
Disallow: /user/*/library/music/
Disallow: /*/+news/*/visit
Disallow: /*/+wiki/diff

# AJAX content
Disallow: /search/autocomplete
Disallow: /template
Disallow: /ajax
Disallow: /user/*/tasteomatic
```

Can I give the URL like this way? I mean, can I specify full URL as disallow?

```
Disallow: http://www.bba-reman.com/admin/feedback.htm
```

### EDIT

my current robots.txt entries looks like below

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /CheckLogin
Disallow: /DTC.pdf
Disallow: /catalogue/bmw.htm
Disallow: /auto-mine/bmw/index.htm
Disallow: /forums/parent.Jmp('i100')
Disallow: /forums/parent.Jmp('i040')
Disallow: /forums/CodeDescriptions.html
Disallow: /forums/parent.Jmp('i050')
Disallow: /forums/parent.Scl('000','24601')
Disallow: /forums/parent.Jmp('i030')
Disallow: /catalogue/peugeot.htm
```

is it ok.....just tell me. thanks

Comment: You can try your robots.txt on google web master tools, and maybe this also can help you,  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en

Comment: Note that [empty lines are not allowed inside a record](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28501875/1591669) (and required between records). A record always starts with `User-agent`, so you should remove the empty lines in your record (or comment them with `#`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the `Disallow` field is always the **beginning of the URL [path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.3)**.

So if your robots.txt is accessible from `http://example.com/robots.txt`, and it contains this line

```
Disallow: http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm
```

then URLs like these would be disallowed:

- `http://example.com/http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm`
- `http://example.com/http://example.com/admin/feedback.html`
- `http://example.com/http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm_foo`
- `http://example.com/http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm/bar`
- …

So if you want to disallow the URL `http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm`, you have to use

```
Disallow: /admin/feedback.htm
```

which would block URLs like these:

- `http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm`
- `http://example.com/admin/feedback.html`
- `http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm_foo`
- `http://example.com/admin/feedback.htm/bar`
- …

Comment: i just post a edit section. please view and tell me is it ok?

Comment: @Mou: Syntactically, it’s correct. However, only you can know if it does what you want to achieve.